# To which version should we upgrade our gitlab ?

Tags: gitlab

We have gitlab ver 7.13.1  on linux red hat 6.3 vm . We need the feature of reverting merge request . To which version should we upgrade our gitlab ? 
Regards, Nir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest, there are lots of security issues that need to be addresses in even the newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

The latest would be best.

But there are a few caveats to look for when upgrading from pre 8.0 :

- If you're using Gitlab CI upgrade to `8.0` first (see [this](https://about.gitlab.com/2017/03/22/gitlab-9-0-released/#upgrade-barometer))
- If you're using Gilab GEO then upgrade to `8.17` (see [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-geo/updating_the_geo_nodes.html))
- If you're using both, upgrade to `8.0` first, then to `8.17`

Finally upgrade to `9.0.2` (latest version at this date).

Comment: thank you , why cant i just upgrade to the latest version ?

Comment: I already put links in my answer detailing why. Basically there were some changes in CI introduced in version `8.0` and you need to go through that version first in order for the changes to be applied correctly. You probably can go straight from 8.0 to 9.0 afterwards.